# XSLT pass array of Integers

Tags: xslt

Hos do I pass array of Integers as a params to XSLT?

Comment: It would be better if you could add more details to your question...

Comment: That's right. What do you mean by 'array of integers'? Would set  of nodes whose values consist of digits only do the job?

Comment: I am trying to filter/Copy the elements in a source XML with the IDs(Integers) as the ID node .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it in an xml format. That would make processing in the xslt easier too.

```
<array>
 <int>23</int>
 <int>45</int>
</array>
```

You can then process it in your xslt as:

```
<xsl:param name="intArray" />
...
...
<xsl:template match="/">
 ...
 <xsl:for-each select="$intArray/int">
  <!-- Process int array -->
  ...
  ...
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It works, but it can lead to [something difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3564329/569101).

Answer (score 0):

Convert it into comma-separated string