# XSLT : Creating a Map in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary

I want to have a key value map in xsl and so defined a variable which has an xml fragment, but later when I try to access the xml nodes in the variable I get an error that type of the xpath xpression cannot be resolved.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
                <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
                <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="$map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's a bit of a typo going on there, is that also in your document? It's <xsl:vlaue-of> which should read <xsl:value-of>.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## XSLT 2.0

Using XSLT 2.0, the following solution works:

```
  <xsl:variable name="map">
    <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
    <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
    <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:value-of select="$map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
```

## XSLT 1.0

You cannot use a result tree fragment in a XPath expression in XSLT 1.0, but `fn:document()` can retrieve map values. An answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564329/how-can-i-select-nodes-from-a-tree-whose-markup-is-stored-in-a-variable/3564550#3564550) will work here:.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='map']/map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
```

As described in the [XSLT 1.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#document):

> `document('')` refers to the root node of
>   the stylesheet; the tree
>   representation of the stylesheet is
>   exactly the same as if the XML
>   document containing the stylesheet was
>   the initial source document.

However, you don't need to use `xsl:variable` for this. You could specify your map node directly under `xsl:stylesheet`, but you must remember that a top level elements must have a non null namespace URI:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:my="some.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="my">

  <my:map>
    <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
    <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
    <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
  </my:map>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/my:map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi,
But then when i did copy-of the result tree fragment was printed properly and not only that even value-of only printed the text nodes in the result tree.

BR,
Keshav

Comment: @Keshav: If you only use `copy-of`/`value-of` on the variable `$map` without trying to use it as a node set, it will work. But once you try to make your way down the result tree fragment with a XPath expression it will fail.

Comment: This is *almost* what I need for my particular problem. What if I want to use an xpath or a $parameter instead of the hard-wired key-1 to lookup the right entry in the map? I've tried <xsl:value-of select="$map/entry[@key='{myxpath}']"/> but that does not work.

Comment: @gilles27: In that case you should use `<xsl:value-of select="$map/entry[@key = $param]"/>` or `...[@key = xpath/of/@choice]`.

Comment: XSLT 3 WD does actually support maps - see my suggestion below.

Answer (score 8):

You can sort of work around XSLT 1.0 missing support for using the variable's contents as a node set. You'll have to rely on extensions added by the parser's maker. For example, Microsoft has offered a function to work around this: node-set()

Your XSL will look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
                <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
                <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($map)/map/entry[@key='key-1']"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the namespace and the msxsl-prefix here. This will only work in applications based on Microsoft's parser (for example: Internet Explorer utilizes it, as well as .NET).
Other parsers may or may not have such an extension (Saxxon does, for example, but it's named a bit differently). But, it eliminates depending on XSLT 2.0, as this will work fine in XSLT 1.0 and Microsoft has yet to support XSLT 2.0 in their XML library (unless they've added it recently).

Depending on the parser you're using, the above may work fine for you, otherwise Per T's answer is better for you.

Comment: +1 Good addition to my answer. Usally I try to avoid vendor specific extensions, but it's definetly one way to solve it!

Comment: @Per_T's answer is better in all cases, because it is a completely *portable* solution. THere are problems that are very difficult to solve without the `xxx:node-set()` extension, but the current problem isn't one of these. Also, in advocating an `xxx:node-set()` solution one should always refer to the `exslt:node-set()`, which is quite portable because many vendors provide EXSLT implementations.

Comment: @Dimitre I must admit Per T's answer has taught me some things about XSL that I didn't know (I'm not an expert), so I didn't know much better and I definitely upvoted his answer for being great. ;) I do slightly argue that, while portability is a very good thing, its importance is context dependent so I wouldn't want to consider my answer quite terrible: it might do fine. ;) It doesn't really pollute your XSL much as it's not too invasive. This is why we're happy about this solution, even if I agree with you that it's not perfect. :) Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 6):

**In XSLT 3.0 Working Draft**, a new kind of XPath item (map) is proposed, see [maps in XSLT 3.0 WD Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#map).

So, if your XSLT processor supports 3.0 and maps (e.g. Saxon 9.4), you can use the following code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" 
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="map" select="
      map { 
      'key-1' : 'value1', 
      'key-2' : 'value2',
      'key-3' : 'value3' }">      
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
      <xsl:value-of select="
        $map('key-1') || ', ' || $map('key-2') || ', ' || $map('key-3')"/> 
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note: The XSLT map syntax is no longer ":=", it's now just ":".

Comment: Just want to add, the '$map' in the <xsl:value-of select=""> part refers to the variable name, thus for variable like <xsl:variable name="MyMap" select="..."> one would use <xsl:value-of select="$MyMap( 'key-1' )">