# Problem using xslt key() function

Tags: xml, xslt, indexing, key

(edited to include suggestions from Martin Honnen)

Hello All,

I've been trying to get the key function to work correctly in the stylesheet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables" >


<xsl:key name="preferences" match="preferences/preference" use="@code"/>

<xsl:template match="Reservation/Detail" >
    <xsl:for-each select="Preferences/Preference">
        <xsl:if test ="string-length(./PreferenceCode)>0">

            &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;* (<xsl:value-of select="./PreferenceCode"/>)

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./PreferenceCode!='PETS'">

                    <xsl:call-template name="prefmap">
                            <xsl:with-param name="code" select="./PreferenceCode"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>

                    <br/><br/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template


<xsl:template name="prefmap">
        <xsl:param name="code"/>
        You got here (called template) with code <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
              <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('preferences',$code)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<m:Maps xmlns="">
<preferences>
        <preference code="ANT">
                Hypoallergenic Bedding
        </preference>
        <preference code="NSK">
                Non-smoking Room
        </preference>
        <preference code="SMK">
                Smoking Room
        </preference>
</preferences>
</m:Maps>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It takes a input (that I don't control) and produces this:

```
* (ANT) You got here (called template) with code ANT


* (EARLY) You got here (called template) with code EARLY


* (NSK) You got here (called template) with code NSK
```

When I was expecting:

```
* (ANT) You got here (called template) with code ANT
  Hypoallergenic Bedding

* (EARLY) You got here (called template) with code EARLY

* (NSK) You got here (called template) with code NSK
Non-smoking Room
```

I tried to include this snippet in the main template to debug, but it produced no output:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="key('preferences',./PreferenceCode)">
                <p>
                    Code: <xsl:value-of select="@code"/><br />
                    Description: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </p>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Do I have a problem with my key definition or the way that I am trying to use it?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Could you please, provide the (smallest possible) XML document on which to apply this transformation?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible -- I ran your transformation on 7 different XSLT processors I am using on a daily basis. THey all produced the same correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have a problem with my key
>   definition or the way that I am trying
>   to use it?

There is no problem with any of them:

**I cannot reproduce the reported output**. This means that if there really is any problem, it is in the code not shown to us.

**The provided transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables" >

    <xsl:key name="preferences" match="preferences/preference" use="@code"/>

    <xsl:template match="Reservation/Detail" >
        <xsl:for-each select="Preferences/Preference">
            <xsl:if test ="string-length(./PreferenceCode)>0">              &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;* (
                <xsl:value-of select="./PreferenceCode"/>)              
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./PreferenceCode!='PETS'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="prefmap">
                            <xsl:with-param name="code" select="./PreferenceCode"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="prefmap">
        <xsl:param name="code"/>         You got here (called template) with code 
        <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
            <xsl:value-of select="key('preferences',$code)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <m:Maps xmlns="">
        <preferences>
            <preference code="ANT">
              Hypoallergenic Bedding
            </preference>
            <preference code="NSK">
             Non-smoking Room
            </preference>
            <preference code="SMK">
             Smoking Room
            </preference>
        </preferences>
    </m:Maps>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (no XML document was provided in the question!):

```
<Reservation>
    <Detail>
        <Preferences>
            <Preference>
              <PreferenceCode>ANT</PreferenceCode>
            </Preference>
            <Preference>
              <PreferenceCode>NSK</PreferenceCode>
            </Preference>
            <Preference>
              <PreferenceCode>SMK</PreferenceCode>
            </Preference>
            <Preference>
              <PreferenceCode>PETS</PreferenceCode>
            </Preference>
        </Preferences>
    </Detail>
</Reservation>
```

**produces exactly the expected result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                      * (
                ANT)              
                         You got here (called template) with code 
        ANT
              Hypoallergenic Bedding
            <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/><br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/>                  * (
                NSK)              
                         You got here (called template) with code 
        NSK
             Non-smoking Room
            <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/><br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/>                  * (
                SMK)              
                         You got here (called template) with code 
        SMK
             Smoking Room
            <br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/><br xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables"/>                  * (
                PETS)
```

**Do Note:**

All the following 7 XSLT processors produce exactly the same (above) result: MSXML3/4, XslCompiledTransform, XslTransform, Saxon 6.5.4, Saxon 9.1.05, AltovaXML (XmlSPY).

Comment: Thanks! I'll point the application developer to this so that they have something to go on. Outstanding effort Dimitre and greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Simon: Glad my question was useful. Here at SO the official form of expressing gratitude is by accepting the right answer. This is done by clicking on the green check-mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: By the way, the XML sample that you ran through the transform is essentially exactly what it should be as a sub-part in a 'real' document. Also, if it helps at all, we used to process the preferences using an <xsl:choose> block which worked fairly well. The biggest reason to switch is just the sheer number of preferences that we now need to include, which went from 5 to 30. Mapping (key()) seemed to be the most maintainable long term, but we're open to any other suggestions.

Comment: @Simon: As I have proved, this cannot be reproduced based on the currently provided data.

Comment: Can I accept both answers as both were very helpful? I tried to vote up both but my rep is too low. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, only one answer can be accepting. Answers can also be upvoted (and one can upvote as many answers as they wish) but to do so one needs to have accumulated 50 (I think) rep. points. You can accept one of the answers and later, when you have accumulated 50 rep. points you can upvote the other answer. In the meantime I already have upvoted Martin's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to put data in your stylesheet with those `preferences/pref` elements? Shouldn't those be in a separate namespace? And keys are built per each document and the `key` function with XSLT 1.0 looks up nodes in the document the context node belongs to. If you want to look up nodes in the stylesheet itself then you need to change the context node first with e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="document('')"><xsl:value-of select="key('preferences', $code)"/></xsl:for-each>`. Then drop the leading `/` from the `match` attribute value and make sure you put the elements in a container element in a separate namespace e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:date="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/java.util.Date"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:m="http://mapping.tables" 
        xmlns:data="http://example.com/data">


<xsl:key name="preferences" match="preferences/pref" use="@code"/>

<data:data xmlns="">
<preferences>
        <pref code="ANT">
                Hypoallergenic Bedding
        </pref>
        <pref code="NSK">
                Non-smoking Room
        </pref>
        <pref code="SMK">
                Smoking Room
        </pref>
</preferences>
</data:data>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've put your suggestions to work but no joy. I am now getting a java.lang.NullPointException whenever it hits that particular piece of logic. Unfortunately I don't have access to any of the backend apart from the ability to upload a stylesheet so I can't get a stack trace or any more detailed error info until the admin of the machine gets back to me. I will keep banging away though.

Comment: Martin, I don't mean to be dense, but would the <xsl:for-each> that references the document('') snippet you suggest go in the 'prefmap' template?

Comment: Simon, the `for-each` snippet is supposed to replace the `<xsl:value-of select="key('preferences',$code)"/>`.

Comment: And make sure you have the `xmlns=""` on the `m:Maps` element containing that `preferences` elements, otherwise your key is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes above but I'm still getting the java.lang.NullPointerException when it tries to do the lookup.

Comment: I wish I could get at the stacktrace. Perhaps it would yield some more useful information.

Comment: Is it possible that this is the problem? --> http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xml-xalan-dev/200409.mbox/%3C1012051172.1094366557188.JavaMail.apache@nagoya%3E

Comment: Do you know which version of which XSLT processor you use? Have you tried some other processor like Saxon (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) instead, to rule out a problem with the processor you use? I am willing to try to run the samples with the latest version from http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/ but to allow us doing that we need some minimal input document you use to produce that error.

Comment: Thanks again Martin. Unfortunately I don't have access directly to the source document, even when I try to use a template to simply scrape the original. It runs under a Weblogic app server so replacing the processor would be problematic. Do you think I could solve this by substituting another template such as was suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626118/xslt-creating-a-map-in-xslt

Comment: I don't know so far why you get that NullPointerException so I can't make suggestions to avoid it. If the `document('')` is the problem then that other post does not help as it also seems to store the mapping in the stylesheet. You could consider to store the mapping in a separate XML document (say "mapping.xml") and then pull that in with `document('mapping.xml')` instead of `document('')` which pulls in the stylesheet.

Comment: I *think* it is xalan-J but I could be wrong. I'm waiting for confirmation from the application developer.