# Bypass XSLT Transformation if only specified values Exist

Tags: xslt

Good evening Experts. My requirement is as follows. I am transforming a target message based on materials that shouldn't be passed. If the target message contains certain materials these are to be removed from the target.

However we are to also check if the target message contains nothing but, **(ONLY)**, these materials then the transformation should not remove these at all.

Currently the code below is to find and remove the materials in question. Please suggest how to ignore the transformation for this new requirement.

Im considering the choose->when->otherwise case.

Many thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='407303']"/>
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='243']"/>
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='262']"/>
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='265']"/>
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='5624']"/>
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR ='145416']"/>
```

Sincere apologies :- Sample input has only 2 line items but should still create this output. You can copy the E1EDP01 bit multiple time to cater for the other IDTNR values.

Thank you Jim.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ORDERS05><IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
    <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
    <IDOCTYP>ORDERS05</IDOCTYP>
    <MESTYP>ORDERS</MESTYP>
    <SNDPOR>SNDPOR</SNDPOR>
    <SNDPRT>KU</SNDPRT>
    <SNDPFC>AG</SNDPFC>
    <SNDPRN>BWH</SNDPRN>
    <RCVPOR>RCVPOR</RCVPOR>
    <RCVPFC>LS</RCVPFC>
    <RCVPRN>RCVPRN</RCVPRN>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
    <BSART>UB</BSART>
    <BELNR>4505345253</BELNR>
    </E1EDK01>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
    <LIFNR>B15</LIFNR>
    <TELF1></TELF1>
    <BNAME></BNAME>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
    <LIFNR>B15</LIFNR>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>LF</PARVW>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <BELNR>4505345253</BELNR>
    <DATUM>20121102T00:00:00</DATUM>
    <UZEIT>20121102T00:00:00</UZEIT>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <POSEX>00001</POSEX>
    <MENGE>1</MENGE>
    <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
    <VPREI>150.00</VPREI>
    <NETWR></NETWR>
    <CURCY>ZAR</CURCY>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <IDTNR>145416</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDID>ZERR</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS_ISO>EN</TSSPRAS_ISO>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Description: GAS CYL DBL NOZZLE 48KG EM</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>UOM: EA</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Quantity: 1</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Unit Price: 150</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Customer Part Number: 145416</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2></E1EDPT1>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <POSEX>00002</POSEX>
    <MENGE>1</MENGE>
    <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
    <VPREI>150.00</VPREI>
    <NETWR></NETWR>
    <CURCY>ZAR</CURCY>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <IDTNR>407303</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDID>ZERR</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS_ISO>EN</TSSPRAS_ISO>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Description: GAS CYL DBL NOZZLE 48KG EM</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>UOM: EA</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Quantity: 1</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Unit Price: 150</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Customer Part Number: 407303</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2></E1EDPT1>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMID>001</SUMID>
    <SUMME>1</SUMME>
    </E1EDS01>
    <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMME>150.00</SUMME>
    <WAERQ>ZAR</WAERQ>
    </E1EDS01>
</IDOC>
```

This example will remove the 2nd line as this contains an item not to be removed by the xslt as well. It should process the 1st line only.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <ORDERS05>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
    <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    <DIRECT>2</DIRECT>
    <IDOCTYP>ORDERS05</IDOCTYP>
    <MESTYP>ORDERS</MESTYP>
    <SNDPOR>SNDPOR</SNDPOR>
    <SNDPRT>KU</SNDPRT>
    <SNDPFC>AG</SNDPFC>
    <SNDPRN>BWH</SNDPRN>
    <RCVPOR>RCVPOR</RCVPOR>
    <RCVPFC>LS</RCVPFC>
    <RCVPRN>RCVPRN</RCVPRN>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
    <BSART>UB</BSART>
    <BELNR>4504836702</BELNR>
    </E1EDK01>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
    <LIFNR>1001600-S78</LIFNR>
    <TELF1></TELF1>
    <BNAME></BNAME>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>WE</PARVW>
    <LIFNR>1001600-S78</LIFNR>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
    <PARVW>LF</PARVW>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <BELNR>4504836702</BELNR>
    <DATUM>20120423T00:00:00</DATUM>
    <UZEIT>20120423T00:00:00</UZEIT>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <POSEX>00001</POSEX>
    <MENGE>100</MENGE>
    <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
    <VPREI>156.18</VPREI>
    <NETWR></NETWR>
    <CURCY>ZAR</CURCY>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <IDTNR>10220</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDID>ZERR</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS_ISO>EN</TSSPRAS_ISO>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Description: GAS 9KG</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>UOM: EA</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Quantity: 100</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Unit Price: 156.18</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Customer Part Number: 10220</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    </E1EDPT1>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDP01 SEGMENT="1">
    <POSEX>00002</POSEX>
    <MENGE>1</MENGE>
    <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
    <VPREI>150.00</VPREI>
    <NETWR></NETWR>
    <CURCY>ZAR</CURCY>
    <E1EDP19 SEGMENT="1">
    <QUALF>001</QUALF>
    <IDTNR>243</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDPT1 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDID>ZERR</TDID>
    <TSSPRAS_ISO>EN</TSSPRAS_ISO>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Description: GAS EMPTY 9 KG</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>UOM: EA</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Quantity: 1</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Unit Price: 150</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    <E1EDPT2 SEGMENT="1">
    <TDLINE>Customer Part Number: 243</TDLINE>
    <TDFORMAT>*</TDFORMAT>
    </E1EDPT2>
    </E1EDPT1>
    </E1EDP01>
    <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMID>001</SUMID>
    <SUMME>2</SUMME>
    </E1EDS01>
    <E1EDS01 SEGMENT="1">
    <SUMME>30618.00</SUMME>
    <WAERQ>ZAR</WAERQ>
    </E1EDS01>
</IDOC>
   </ORDERS05>
```

Comment: Some sample input XML and desired output would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your result by double negating (you want to copy the root directly only there are NOT elements which are NOT in you materials list).

Here you have a sample transformation.

BTW: I made use of "map" variable to simplify the validations, like the one suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626118/xslt-creating-a-map-in-xslt) post. In case you are using XSLT 2.0, you can simplify it a bit more following the idea on the same post (use a variable directly, instead of using document('')).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mat="materials" exclude-result-prefixes="mat">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <mat:materials>
        <IDTNR>407303</IDTNR>
        <IDTNR>243</IDTNR>
        <IDTNR>262</IDTNR>
        <IDTNR>265</IDTNR>
        <IDTNR>5624</IDTNR>
        <IDTNR>145416</IDTNR>
    </mat:materials>
    <xsl:variable name="materials" select="document('')/*/mat:materials/IDTNR"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="E1EDP01[E1EDP19/IDTNR = $materials]"/>
    <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template match="ORDERS05[not(IDOC/E1EDP01/E1EDP19[not(IDTNR=$materials)])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope this helps!

Carles

Comment: Carles. Thank you so much for this. Worked like a charm in my tests. Going to adapt the <xsl:variable name="materials" select="document('')/*/mat:materials/IDTNR"/> to match my requirement of checking at runtime on the segments in question. Will update...